# How to use urllib2 in two classes at the same time

Tags: python, urllib2

I am writing a sync script.
I wrote two classes to do it

```
class jira:
    def __init__(self, site, username, password):
        cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
        opener = urllib2.build_opener()
        opener.add_handler(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
        self.topurl = site
        loginUrl = deepcopy(self.topurl)
        loginUrl += '/rest/auth/1/session'
        user = {"username": username, "password": password}
        req = urllib2.Request(loginUrl)
        req.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        req.add_data(json.dumps(user))
        try:
            res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
            print str(err)
            sys.exit(2)
```

and

```
class clearquest:
    def __init__(self, site, username, password):
        pwdmgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
        pwdmgr.add_password(None, site, username, password)
        handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(pwdmgr)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
        try:
            opener.open(site)
        except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
            print str(err)
            sys.exit(2)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

First I inited class clearquest and then inited jira

```
cq = clearquest(site, username, passowrd)
jr = jira(site, username, password)
```

Then I want use them to do something, but when I used cq, it point out "Unauthorized"

I know it must be jira's opener overwrite clearquest's opener, but how can I avoid it?

Comment: Are you using the correct username and password?

Comment: yes,it is OK when run either class, maybe I shouldn't use urllib2.install_opener(opener) and just use opener.open() to open req. tomorry I will try it.

Comment: Just a tip, try urllib3 instead: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/urllib3 It works around a lot of the issues in urllib and urllib2. A simple `make_headers` will do the trick: http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html?highlight=basic_auth#urllib3.util.request.make_headers

Comment: Have you tried attaching a packet sniffer (tcpdump in Linux, Wireshark in Windows) and seeing what is happening? That will probably point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already resolved it

```
class jira:
def __init__(self, site, username, password):
    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
    self.opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    self.opener.add_handler(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    self.topurl = site
    loginUrl = deepcopy(self.topurl)
    loginUrl += '/rest/auth/1/session'
    user = {"username": username, "password": password}
    req = urllib2.Request(loginUrl)
    req.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.add_data(json.dumps(user))
    try:
        res = self.opener.open(req)
    except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
        print str(err)
        sys.exit(2)
```

Just not use urllib2.install_opener(opener), it will install current opener and overwrite pre installation, and use self.opener.open() instead of urllib.urlopen(),it will use the class's opener to open request